# print a highlighted text in acrobat reader

Tags: printing, acrobat

I am trying to print a pdf document annotated with yellow highlights. While printing this document, my printer does not print the highlights and prints only the text. Also, I can't find any settings.
I have acrobat reader 9.

Answer (score 4):

In print dialog box there is a dropdown menu for "comments and Forms". Selecting "documnet and markups" would print the highlights too.

Comment: Should also check that "print in greyscale" is NOT selected :(